# Insert Blobs in MySql databases with php

Tags: php, mysql, blob

I am trying to store an image in the DataBase, for some reason it doesn't seem to work. Here's the structure of my table.

```
mysql> describe ImageStore;
+---------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field   | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| ImageId | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| Image   | longblob | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+---------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

And here is my query which inserts the image or at least thats what it should:

```
//Store the binary image into the database
                $tmp_img = $this->image['tmp_name'];
                $sql = "INSERT INTO ImageStore(ImageId,Image)               
                VALUES('$this->image_id','file_get_contents($tmp_image)')";
                mysql_query($sql);
```

If I print the value of file_get_contents($tmp_image), then there is a tons of data on the screen. But this value doesn't get stored in the database and that is the issue that I'm facing.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

#### Problem

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO ImageStore(ImageId,Image)
        VALUES('$this->image_id','file_get_contents($tmp_image)')";
```

This creates a string in PHP named `$sql`. Forget about MySQL for a minute, because you're not executing any query yet. You're just building a string.

The magic of PHP means that you can write a variable name — say, `$this->image_id` — *inside* the double quotes and the variable still gets magically expanded.

This functionality, known as "variable interpolation", does not occur for function calls. So, all you're doing here is writing the string `"file_get_contents($tmp_image)"` into the database.

---

#### Solution (1)

So, to concatenate the result of calling `file_get_contents($tmp_image)`, you have to jump out of the string and do things explicitly:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO ImageStore(ImageId,Image)
        VALUES('$this->image_id','" . file_get_contents($tmp_image) . "')";
```

(You can see even just from the syntax highlighting how this has worked.)

---

#### Solution (2)

Now the problem you have is that if the binary data contains any `'`, your query is not valid. So you should run it through `mysql_escape_string` to sanitize it for the query operation:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO ImageStore(ImageId,Image)
        VALUES('$this->image_id','" . mysql_escape_string(file_get_contents($tmp_image)) . "')";
```

---

#### Solution (3)

Now you have a *really* big string, and your database is getting bulky.

[Prefer not storing images in databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492549/how-can-i-insert-large-files-in-mysql-db-using-php), where you can help it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit. Re "prefer not storing large files in db".. well that depends on *what* db.

Answer (score 4):

To expand on Tomalak's comment, you can't run a function inside of quotes.

Try:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO ImageStore(ImageId,Image)               
        VALUES('{$this->image_id}','".file_get_contents($tmp_image)."')";
```

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
$tmp_img = $this->image['tmp_name'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO ImageStore(ImageId,Image)               
  VALUES('$this->image_id','" . addslashes(file_get_contents($tmp_image)) . "')";
mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: "Please note that use of addslashes() for database parameter escaping can be cause of security issues on most databases." - [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php)

Comment: PDO:: uses prepare(), but it should use also addslashes() something like, so we shall prefer the PHP.Native solution that is addslashes(). It works prefectly.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned you are just saving the string `"file_get_contents($tmp_image)"` into the db 
but you need to run the function `file_get_contents` instead

dont forget to hash the image using a hashing algorithm such as `base64_encode` before saving it to the db.

Comment: images may contents some illegal words (such as -- , " , ' and so on...) and this may cause problem while we are executing the query

Comment: without hashing or any other checks this may cause sql injection attacks

Comment: You don't need hashing at all. Just escape single quotes and backslashes to keep from breaking out of string mode.

Comment: You are right , but there is another option , we can send and recive images like a string to and from the browser , most browser can convert a base64 string to image , but for sql injections and custom errors i trust your solution