# get the BLOB value of an image and insert it to database in php

Tags: php, blob

I have this code:

```
$filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$blob_value = [CODE TO CONVERT FILENAME TO BINARY];

$query = "INSERT INTO uploads VALUES('$blob_value');";
mysql_query($query);
```

I want to convert the image file to its equivalent blob_value and insert it to database. how am i suppose to do that. thank you for your response!

Comment: don't, store the file in the file system and any details you need in the db.

Comment: Dont bother database, store images as file

Comment: but our professor said to compare if the image exist using blob. but how am i suppose to do that in database?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this is what you need

```
$fileName = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
$tmpName  = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
$fileSize = $_FILES['userfile']['size'];
$fileType = $_FILES['userfile']['type'];

$fp      = fopen( $tmpName, 'r' );

$content = fread( $fp, filesize( $tmpName ) );

fclose( $fp );

$query = "INSERT INTO upload ( name, size, type, content ) ".
"VALUES ( '$fileName', '$fileSize', '$fileType', '$content' )";

mysql_query( $query ) or die( 'Error, query failed' );
```

Theres probably lots of different ways to do this though, i haven't tried this code...

Comment: if i base the validation on the image file size will it be better than getting its BLOB value?

Comment: No why would you do that, then the chance of getting the same hash if more than one image has the same size. I think it's better to do it on the file itself.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you're looking for `$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']`, which is the file holding the *file data*. Just the file name itself isn't of much use.

Secondly, the "BLOB value" of a file is just the binary data of the file, i.e. the file contents. So all you need to do to get the file "BLOB" data is:

```
$blob = file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
```

Third, storing large files is not really what a database was designed for. You should store the file in the file system and only information *about* the file in the database. If you want to check whether you already have the exact same file, store a [*hash*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) of the file in the database, which you can easily search for.

Comment: thanks! but what if the user uploaded images with different FILENAME but the same image. i want to detect that even the FILENAME is different but the IMAGE itself is the same . the image still exists.

Comment: do i need to put addslashes()?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7052655/insert-blobs-in-mysql-databases-with-php

Comment: if i base the validation on the image file size will it be better than getting its BLOB value?

Comment: Again, **use a hash**. Seeing that you're still learning this may be an advanced topic, but it's the best solution. Generate a hash from the file's content, store that in the database, check for each new file if its hash is already known.

Comment: im sorry for being noob. but what particular field am i going to hash?? the [name] or [size] or [tmp_name]??

Comment: The whole file, i.e. `file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])`.