# storing images in mysql database doesn't work. What now?

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload

I am trying for days now to upload images to my database and then to display them. But in my script seems to be a mistake, and I can't find it :( So now I hope someone from this community can help me in this case - that would be really great! Thanks very much! I know it is much to read, sorry.

Here is the code form insert.php:

```
<?php
/*Enter your password on line 29*/
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);



if(!isset($_FILES['userfile']))
{
    echo '<p>Please select a file</p>';
}
else
{
    try {
    $msg= upload();  //this will upload your image
    echo $msg;  //Message showing success or failure.
    }
    catch(Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    echo 'Sorry, could not upload file';
    }
}

// the upload function

function upload() {
    $host="localhost";
$user="YYYY";
$pass="XXXX";
$db="ibm_sfreund";

    $maxsize = 10000000; //set to approx 10 MB

    //check associated error code
    if($_FILES['userfile']['error']==UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {

        //check whether file is uploaded with HTTP POST
        if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'])) {    

            //checks size of uploaded image on server side
            if( $_FILES['userfile']['size'] < $maxsize) {  

               //checks whether uploaded file is of image type
              //if(strpos(mime_content_type($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']),"image")===0) {
                 $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
                if(strpos(finfo_file($finfo, $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']),"image")===0) {    

                    // prepare the image for insertion
                    $imgData =addslashes (file_get_contents($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']));

                    // put the image in the db...
                    // database connection
                    $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "...", "...");
                    mysql_select_db('...',$con);

                    // our sql query
                    $id_xd = $_POST["id"];
                    $sql = "UPDATE artikel SET image='{$imgData}', name='{$_FILES['userfile']['name']}', mime='{$_FILES['userfile']['type']}' WHERE id='$id_xd';";

                    // insert the image
                    mysql_query($sql) or die("Error in Query: " . mysql_error());
                    $msg='<p>Image successfully saved in database.</p>';
                }
                else
                    $msg="<p>Uploaded file is not an image.</p>";
            }
             else {
                // if the file is not less than the maximum allowed, print an error
                $msg='<div>File exceeds the Maximum File limit</div>
                <div>Maximum File limit is '.$maxsize.' bytes</div>
                <div>File '.$_FILES['userfile']['name'].' is '.$_FILES['userfile']['size'].
                ' bytes</div><hr />';
                }
        }
        else
            $msg="File not uploaded successfully.";

    }
    else {
        $msg= file_upload_error_message($_FILES['userfile']['error']);
    }
    return $msg;
}

// Function to return error message based on error code

function file_upload_error_message($error_code) {
    switch ($error_code) {
        case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE:
            return 'The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini';
        case UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE:
            return 'The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form';
        case UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL:
            return 'The uploaded file was only partially uploaded';
        case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE:
            return 'No file was uploaded';
        case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR:
            return 'Missing a temporary folder';
        case UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE:
            return 'Failed to write file to disk';
        case UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION:
            return 'File upload stopped by extension';
        default:
            return 'Unknown upload error';
    }
}
```

Here is the script to displaying the picture:

```
<?php
 // just so we know it is broken
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
 // some basic sanity checks
 if(isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id'])) {
     //connect to the db
     $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "...", "...");
     mysql_select_db('...',$con);

     // get the image from the db
     $sql = "SELECT image,mime FROM artikel WHERE id=" .$_GET['id'] . ";";

     // the result of the query
     $result = mysql_query("$sql") or die("Invalid query: " . mysql_error());
        $row = mysql_fetch_object($result);     

     /*Only to check output*/           
     $img_final = $row->image;
     echo $img_final;

     /*Only to check output*/

 }
 else {
     echo 'Please use a real id number';
 }
```

I don't know what the mistake is, but this is what it shows after opening the site for displaying the pic:

```
Deprecated: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in /users/ibm/www/beta/loadpic.php on line 7
GIF87a^–ãÌÌÌ–––···£££œœœªªª¾¾¾ÅÅÅ±±±,^–þÈI«½8ëÍ»ÿ`(Ždižhª®lë¾p,Ïtmßx®ï|ïÿÀ pH,È¤rÉl:ŸÐ¨tJ­Z¯Ø¬vËíz¿à°xL.›Ïè´zÍn»ßð¸|N¯Ûïø¼~Ïïûÿ€‚ƒ„…†‡ˆ‰Š‹ŒŽ‘’“”•–—˜™š›œžŸ ¡¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª«¬­®¯°±²³´µ¶·¸¹º»¼½¾¿ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàRëìíìåBïîûëðòëõÂ80ÏüöeÀoÀ LØnaCp)´@±âþô@ P_Ç~C~‹H`€»tÚ (@³&MÉµ³—"¿‰mÚÄ)3"ÏmÙñÌ£Ò$ÙÁt¹Ž@Ž¨?M®;Êk€©ì¬r£`£¯b>õPP¤Ro$eGV¢Ö\7´wLmñÌU8Ðî¯„Ç°÷Æ<æÚuº5qa ¹0|xíÄæŠ€Õá Ò¯ÑJœ Ø¯ÚÊð5¥ÀZo;³^GèMÙunºˆD{»ì¿sœ'uË·juíFGœ<ÜcqÏÑa˜^¡o€ë3îh3»ö/kØ—¶v>Ê)œ„/¡ |ûÑiþSSvèuÖQ^ø7h€÷^Àù­w  R`‚ÚìC@ÒU×yÍ!È XY•¡†Ðˆž"‡Ùì3ˆuã[êç™…ÆqPl$´˜#]ª™ŸŒ0Ù¡‡8®Ÿn‚ùˆ›•An Ù!)S†Ubq4nãÓn˜‡“N• ^b &–&rùy^ {ëü×æ[–šw–-Öß{Úù yœ¸¢{~àÎ q¶ÆÕ£ñºœ˜þÈhuìD ¨;‚RHh§W¹u<†:Û—§Î÷#•¦MPiÛ Çb¬œHkr¼ZsºBÈ)mÔJ›|°þVÛ±]……h‘ÁÆ£,¤Ì®­±Î"Åå¯¤q9ç²šªç›_ÛâÇ+Vy‹m¹ì°Š ‘ŒMÛl•ávËgÔáéldM8è}¼m›"†ñ‚jÛ6öÕÊ–; ¤^¥ïjëê®CœdT,YÅbC¥9:%ü¬L0^“Q¹‘\oP[PS]5­,¢;8¾ü§5#xAÐmšçÎµØÙëJ½vdÑŠJLÒ€ñÐ º%šMoœi°ÅeUÔZ_$jå´TªÄÏñÌÐ][WÉw‰]^Ûocü=k¿*øà„nøáˆ'®øâŒ7îøãG.ùä”WnùåN˜g®ùæœwîùç ‡.úè¤—núé¨§®úê¬·îúë°Ç.ûì´×nûí¸ç®ûî¼÷îûïÀ/üðÄoüñÈ'¯üòÌ7ïüóÐG/ýôsD;
```

This is a screenshot of the mysql structure:
[Link to screenshot](http://ibm.bplaced.com/curus/Bildschirmfoto%202015-04-11%20um%2015.15.03.png)

I hope you can help me!
Thanks so much!!

Comment: Doing `echo $img_final;` is normal for your output to be `GIF87a^–ãÌÌÌ...`

Comment: So what should I do?

Comment: Yeah I already tried this, but it doesn't work

Comment: @mmibm What did you try exactly? `<img src="/your/php/script.php">` should come close. And you have an sql injection problem.

Comment: @jeroen This:   `echo "<img src='$img_final'>";`

Comment: Which means the browser will try to fetch `GIF87a^–ãÌÌÌ–––···£££œœœªªª¾¾¾ÅÅÅ±±...` from the server. No, that won't work...

Comment: You'd make your life a lot easier if you just store the image on the file-server and the path in the database.

Comment: @jeroen Storing images on fileserver is not always the best solution.

Comment: <img src=".."> I tryed this now. also doesnt work... How can i do this, storing the image on the file server then path in database?

Comment: @yergo Perhaps not always, but it is if you are storing images up to 10Mb and are using stuff like `add_slashes` on your image data.

Comment: I would be so happy if one of u guys could help me :)

Comment: @mmibm If you want to store the files as images, check the manual on file uploads: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Comment: And how do i save the link automaticlly to the database then?

Comment: @yergo In my opinion, jeroen's proposal is right. You should not store images as blobs/raw_data on the database. You can create a `directory` inside your web-development space, and create an` md5/openssl string` as  directory's name. Then in this directory you save (again) with a hash as image name. So you only have  to `store to the database`  two hashes, for getting the image.

Comment: @yergo

Structure : `/photo_uploads/md5(dir1)/md5(name)`
The `Structure` makes quite hard for the site to be crawled and if you set `dir1` to have a fixed size(e.g. 30 pics/dir) then you can create directories and search through less files by knowing the dir_name on the database.

Comment: @ThemisBeris how about couple of servers hidden under balance-loader sharing a lot os same static content. Even separate static server can have a performance hiccup when under 1k/rps it has to fetch everything from filesystem. Sometimes it IS performance-wise to fetch content from db, to cache it in eg. varnish. This qustion is not about best practice to serve pictures, but how to do it with provided code.

Comment: @yergo You can optimize/cache files on the web server too. And i don't think that Stackoverflow's aim is to give you working code.

Answer (score 0):

> Deprecated: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in /users/ibm/www/beta/loadpic.php on line 7

You should rewrite your code to use PDO or mysqli. To make it working just now, try using:

```
 error_reporting(0);
 ini_set('display_errors', 0);
```

but thats not a solution, rather thing to test if its working at all. As you are able to share binary data to us, that error at the beginning is all that crushes your script.

**header:**
Also you need to send a proper header, to let browser recognise that this is an image, not a webpage. Once you use here a GIf, you can try:

```
header("Content-type: " . image_type_to_mime_type(IMAGETYPE_GIF));
```

before sending first output. But you need to check mime type out before saving an image to db ans save it too. Then you can fetch it with binary data and send back when displaying.

**addslashes** is not quite necessary. Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7052685/4615331) answer and adjust your code.

Comment: Now it shows only the letters and so on without the warning. But how can i display the image?

Comment: @mm: you will need a `Content-type` header as well. [Try this search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=Content-type+header+PHP+GIF).

Comment: Isn't there any other mistake in the script that might crash everything?

Comment: Content-type was not working previously or is not working in current state? Plase check my update and test it out.

Comment: Ok now it says the image cannot be show cause it contains errors?