# Save an Image to mysql

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jlabel

[click here to open image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfvG2.jpg)

This is an image captured from a web cam, and save it to an label. no url used. can i get the image from the label and save it to mysql? NOT USING URL

maybe with getIcon() method?

Comment: you could create a column of type BLOB(Binary Large Object), which is designed for this kind of data - this may be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7052655/insert-blobs-in-mysql-databases-with-php

Comment: this is not what i want. i know how to save image to mysql. my question is how to get image from label without using url. the label image was an captured by the web cam.

Answer (score 1):

> is how to get image from label

You can create a `BufferedImage` from any Swing component. The basic code is:

```
BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(label.getWidth(), label.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
Graphics2D g2d = image.createGraphics();
label.paint( g2d );
g2d.dispose();
```

Or you can check out [Screen Image](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/13/screen-image/) which adds extra features to the above code to make it more flexible. Then you can just use:

```
BufferedImage image = ScreenImage.createImage( label );
```