# Insert Blobs in MySql databases with php mysqli_escape_string not working

Tags: html, file, blob

I have the same problem as this one [Insert Blobs in MySql databases with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7052655/insert-blobs-in-mysql-databases-with-php) but my files are music files and somehow the answers are not working for me.

This is my database:

```
+---------+-----------+------+----+--------+--------------+   
| Field   |    Type   | Null |Key |Default |Extra         |  
+---------+-----------+------+----+--------+--------------+  
|music_id |int(11)    |  NO  |PRI |NULL    |auto_increment|  
|mp3      |longblob   |  YES |    |NULL    |              |  
|mime     |varchar(30)|  NO  |    |NULL    |              |
+---------+-----------+------+----+--------+--------------+
```

This is my form in html:

```
<form method="post" action="uploadFile.php" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    <label>Upload a file with blob datatype</label><br>
    <input type="file" name="Upfile" required="" accept= "audio/*">
    <input type="submit" name="submit_Upfile" value="Submit">
</form>
```

This is my php file:

```
<?php 
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pword = "";
$db = "musics";
$con = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pword,$db);

if($con)
{
if(isset($_POST["submit_Upfile"]))
{
    $audio_name= mysqli_escape_string($con,basename( $_FILES["Upfile"]["name"] ));

    $audio_content = mysqli_escape_string($con,file_get_contents($_FILES['Upfile']['tmp_name']));

    $audio_size = getimagesize($_FILES["Upfile"]["tmp_name"]);
    $audio_content = base64_encode($audio_content);
    echo "audio_size here => ".$audio_size["mime"]."<br>";
    echo "audio_name here => ".$audio_name."<br>";
    echo "audio_content here => ".$audio_content."<br>";

    $insert_audio_to_db = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO `mp3s`( `mp3` ,`mime`) VALUES ('".$audio_content."','".$audio_size['mime']."')" );
    if($insert_audio_to_db)
    {
        echo "Insert successful.";
    }else
    echo "Insert failed.";
}
}
else
echo "Connection error.";

?>
```

I tried to echo some things and this is what I got:

```
audio_size here => 
audio_name here => iMessage Send and Receive Sounds.mp3
audio_content here => [too long to display]
Insert failed.
```

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I have found the answer of this question with the help of my colleague [Diana Llona](https://www.facebook.com/dianacute00). We will share it to others who are experiencing the same problem.

### Problem: The main problem here is that `xampp` has a default max size of upload files.

To change it follow these steps:

1. Open your `Xampp Control Panel`.  [See image here.](https://prnt.sc/ft7yyk)
2. On the row of your `Apache`click the [config](http://prntscr.com/ft80fv) button. Find the `PHP (php.ini)` file.
3. It will open the `php.ini` file for you and there, find the `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size`.
4. Change it to your desired size then save and close the file. (I just changed the [post_max_size this](http://prntscr.com/ft82a7) and [upload_max_filesize](http://prntscr.com/ft83rp) that big because I just want to.)

Next is to change the `innodb_log_file_size` of the `MySQL`.

1. Click the `config` button for your `MySQL` on the `Xampp Control Panel`. [See image here](http://prntscr.com/ft86q3)
2. Then find the `innodb_log_file_size` and change it to your desired size then save and close the file. [See image here](https://prnt.sc/ft84sx)

After you've done these steps, restart your `Apache` and `MySQL` by clicking the `Stop` button and `Start` it again.