# Converting files to blob to save in database

Tags: php, mysql, blob

I have an old user site that we are currently updating. The site's users have previously uploaded profile pics that are stored in a directory. I am now wanting to keep these profile images in the database, (easy to backup all data) but am having trouble working out how to do it.

There are a lot of tutorials talking about do ing this from files that have just been uploaded and using the tmp name etc, but how can I re-create with files that have already been uploaded?

I have looked into 
`$data = file_get_contents($filename);`
Which seems to create a binary file, but doesn't seem to save in database with:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE profiles SET company_logo = mysql_real_escape_string('".$data."') WHERE id = 1 ") or die(mysql_error());
```

****UPDATE****
So after looking into this some more, I think I will go with the majority and save the images as they already are... in folders..

Comment: Please please please don't do that. The filesystem is an awesome database for files.

Comment: You really shouldn't store files in the database.  There are good reasons why files should stay in the filesystem.  Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492549/how-can-i-insert-large-files-in-mysql-db-using-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's generally a bad idea to store images in the database.

It is better to store the images in a file and keep a reference in a field or table.

However, if you want to store them, you must store them as BLOB (Binairy Large OBject). On a BLOB field, no character translation is done. When you store them, you must store them exactly as the file contents. So remove the `mysql_real_escape string`, as it will mess up your binary data.

Comment: Why is it a bad idea to store image in database? I know the loading times might be slightly slower...

Comment: It always difficult not to start a war on db image storage :) Have a look ath this discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay

Comment: Remove mysql_real_escape_string may be dangerous.  Thinks what would happen if you actually have something like `'); drop table x;` in the file?  A _much_ better approach would be to use prepared statements and then execute them with the blob data.  That way DB server/driver would handle any necessary conversion itself.

Comment: For the blob storage, you have to remove the mysql_real_escape_string, otherwise the binary data will(could) mess up, depending on the contents. I agree, that if you store binary data, one always should use parameter binding.